# Records in DB are not one by one. Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have db table Users with two columns : ID (AI) and NAME (UNIQUE).
When I'm adding new record to db everything is ok, this record has ID = 1.

When I'm trying to add record with existing name I'm getting error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry
```

I want to add next record, with valid data and this record has ID = 3.

Is any solution to avoid it? I want to have have ID's like this:

1 | 2 | 3

not

1 | 3 | 5 etc.

or maybe should I first check if this name exist? Which option is better?

My code:

```
public boolean save(){
    hibernate.beginTransaction();
    hibernate.save(userObject);
    hibernate.getTransaction().commit();
    hibernate.close();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want the IDs in row? It may look a bit irritating but those gaps should not hurt. If you later on delete users, they will leave gaps too.

Comment: Do you mean that I should use name as Primary Key and Unique ?

Comment: I mean, 1,2,3,5,6,9,10,11,15 is a perfect row for IDs

Comment: Ok, thanks. What do you think about "or maybe should I first check if this name exist? Which option is better?" ?

Comment: I know people who prefer to check if that name exists (and they see constructs like "INSERT IGNORE" as evil), but no one could convince me yet. I see extra overhead in code and in runtime with no point. Just be sure to catch the Error/Exception at the right point. I have no idea how to put stuff like INSERT IGNORE and affected_rows (0 or 1) in Hibernate, otherwise that would be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ID generation strategies. If ID is generated based on sequence then its last number is immediately incremented whenever "next value" is requested. There won't be a problem you described if ID is generated based on table.